# Convert Excel spreadshhet to online grid with simple calculations

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to convert an excel spreadsheet to an online grid, including the ability to perform calculations that are in the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

I have search for some resources that may help you:

- http://www.igniteui.com/javascript-excel-library/excel-formulas
- http://codetheory.in/parse-read-excel-files-xls-xlsx-javascript/

The first one is a library that help you to use excel formulas and the second one is a nice excel file parser.

Hope this helps.

Comment: to evaluate excel formulas you can try https://github.com/fabiooshiro/xlsx-calc